# Outlook sending mutliple Confirmation Emails for booked ressources

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, meeting-request

So since 2 days ago, we have this problem where Users get multiple Confirmations for bookings of Rooms or Ressources.

- User creates meeting with Room/Laptop added
- Meeting is successfully put in calendar
- Room/Laptop is configured to automatically accept requests (always has been)
- User receives many identical confirmation emails from that ressource in irregular intervals (between 1 and 15 minutes) until you cancel that meeting

What I've tried so far:

- connect to exchange online powershell and change many parameters in the get-calendarprocessing section
- Disable the Automatic processing and enable it again in the exchange center
- Removed and Re-Add the confirmation message
- create a new ressource with default settings. Same thing there

[Email inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZUuc.png)

Comment: According to your description, I noticed that this issue happend two days ago. Did you hvave any special operations two days ago?

In addition, what is the version of your exchange server? And have you updated your exchange server recently or installed any CU/SU?

Comment: @Christy We're running Exchange 2016 version 15.20.4415.19 cloud hosted. As far as I know there have been no changes made, it seems it happened by itself

Comment: I found a problem similar to your issue. Please pay attention to this thread to get some useful information: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2328537-resource-mailboxes?from_forum=33

Comment: @Christy Get-MessageTrackingLog is only available for on-permise exchange.

Comment: @Washbear For Exchange 2016, message tracking log is available. For Exchange Online, you could perform a message trace(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/monitoring/trace-an-email-message/run-a-message-trace-and-view-results) and see if there is any exception.

Comment: Hi, any update?

Comment: @Ivan_Wang It does work now again. I am not sure about this, because I did change many parameters in the mailbox configuration over powershell, but I believe what did the trick was to set "Set-Mailbox email@domain.com -CalendarRepairDisabled $true"

Comment: I think you could monitor this issue for a while, if the same issue happens, you could run a message trace to view the whole mail flow, maybe it helps.